# Angularjs with rest api using SQLALCHEMEY joined tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a webapp that uses angularjs and a backend api build in flask and sqlalchemy. The problem is that some keys in the json contain a dot and angularjs can't handle this. The problem is with the location.name field.

This is the json from the api

> {
>      "brand": "Unknown",
>      "id": 6,
>      "location.name": "USB",
>      "name": "Usb verlengkabel 0.5m",
>      "uri": "http://localhost:5000/items/6"
>   }

And this is my angular controller:

```
  angular
  .module('inventory')
  .controller('Item.ItemEditController', Controller);

  function Controller($stateParams,$http) {
      var ctrl = this;
              $http.get(config.API_URL+'/items'+'/'+$stateParams.itemId ).success(function(data) {
                ctrl.item = data;
            }).error(function(data){ctrl.errormsg = data});

      ctrl.updateItem = function () {
        $http({
              method: 'PUT',
              url: config.API_URL +'/items/' + $stateParams.itemId,
              data : this.item
              })
              .then(function successCallback(response) {
                  ctrl.result = { class:'alert alert-success', message:'Opgeslagen!'};
                  console.log(ctrl.result);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                  console.log("error")
                  ctrl.result = { class:'alert alert-danger', message:'Er is iets fout gegaan bij het opslaan'};
                });
      }
  }
```

And the html page

```
                <div ng-if="ctrl.result.class" ng-class="ctrl.result.class">
                  {{ctrl.result.message}}
                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="ctrl.updateItem()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.item.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="brand" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Brand</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.item.brand" class="form-control" id="brand" placeholder="brand" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.location.name" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="location" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ctrl.item['location.name']` instead of `ctrl.location.name`

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="location" 
       placeholder="location" 
       ng-model="ctrl.item['location.name']" />
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/V2LsFL7SNMV8n5nkLQWa?p=preview